# Image upload and path to custom field

Tags: custom-field, images, uploads

I build a script, to post from frontend. There are many custom-fields. Most works fine, but with one thing i have problems.

First a description, then the script.

It seems like, that images won't upload, cause i can't find them in the upload-directory or anywhere else. The cutom-field will be generated, that's no problem. I say that, cause the field appears at the backend - but empty. I think it's empty, cause it doesn't upload. Yes, for testing i have put 777 to my serversettings for the upload-directory, so i think the server is not disabling the upload.

P.S.: I shortened the code to make it clear. If you want the hole code, just say a word.

Thank you for helping!

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
    // Funktion zum Image-Upload, falls sie noch nicht existiert
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' )) { 
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }

    // Variablen für die Bilder
    $image_1_gesucht = wp_handle_upload( $file['image_1_gesucht'] );
    $image_2_gesucht = wp_handle_upload( $file['image_2_gesucht'] );

    // Benutzerdefinierfte Felder für die Bilder
    add_post_meta($pid,'image_1_gesucht',$image_1_gesucht['url']);
    add_post_meta($pid,'image_2_gesucht',$image_2_gesucht['url']);
}

<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="pro50left">
        <fieldset class="images">
            <label for="images">Bild 1:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image_1_gesucht" id="image_1_gesucht">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="pro50left">
        <fieldset class="images">
            <label for="images">Bild 2:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image_2_gesucht" id="image_2_gesucht">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Forgot 2 lines of code. New is line 2 and line 11. I post the complete code:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
    $file=$_FILES;
    // Funktion zum Image-Upload, falls sie noch nicht existiert
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' )) { 
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }

    // Variablen für die Bilder
    $overrides = array( 'test_form' => false);
    $image_1_gesucht = wp_handle_upload( $file['image_1_gesucht'], $overrides );
    $image_2_gesucht = wp_handle_upload( $file['image_2_gesucht'], $overrides );

    // Benutzerdefinierfte Felder für die Bilder
    add_post_meta($pid,'image_1_gesucht',$image_1_gesucht['url']);
    add_post_meta($pid,'image_2_gesucht',$image_2_gesucht['url']);
}

<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="pro50left">
        <fieldset class="images">
            <label for="images">Bild 1:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image_1_gesucht" id="image_1_gesucht">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="pro50left">
        <fieldset class="images">
            <label for="images">Bild 2:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image_2_gesucht" id="image_2_gesucht">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```